# Redirect with "componentDidMount()" : problem (React)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I have some code that works. It immediately reroutes a user from the `/test` page to the `FinishedPaying` page. It is as so:

```
class Test extends Component {
  renderRedirect = () => {
      return <Redirect to="/FinishedPaying" />;
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderRedirect();
  }
...
```

The following code is meant to send a `Paypal` transaction, then route the user to the `/FinishedPaying` page. All of the other logic is working as expected:

```
export default class Pay extends React.Component {
  state = {
    userInput: ""
  };
  renderRedirect = () => {
      return (
        <Redirect
          to="/FinishedPaying"
          userInput={this.state.userInput}
        />
      );
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ userInput: this.props.userInput });
    this.renderRedirect();
  }

  render() {
    const onSuccess = payment => {
      axios
        .post(
          "http://amazonaws.com:3000/ethhash",
          {
            userInput: this.props.userInput,
          }
        )

        .then(response => console.log(response.data, payment))

        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <PaypalExpressBtn
          onSuccess={onSuccess}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Not sure why the second code block is working. It is my understanding that `this.renderRedirect()` should fire after all of the other logic has happened. It does not seem to be firing at all. Any feedback is appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What component lifecycle to use to do something before render()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194045/what-component-lifecycle-to-use-to-do-something-before-render)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can put it in your `render` like:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.redirect){
        return <Redirect
            to="/FinishedPaying"
            userInput={this.state.userInput}
            />;
    }
    const onSuccess = payment => {...}
```

As soon as you change your `redirect` value in `state` for `true` you will be redirected.

Comment: Thank you, this works renders correctly, but executes before the Paypal logic. If I put it after the Paypal logic, Paypal executes but the page does not redirect.

Comment: Just change `redirect` value state when your Paypal logic done. you can do with `this.setState({'redirect': true})`

Answer (score 2):

You can't return the component `<Redirect to="/FinishedPaying" />` in componentDidMount, you can only do that in `render()`.

You could have a flag that sets to true when you're ready to redirect:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    userInput: this.props.userInput,
    readyToRedirect: true
  });
}
```

Then in your `render` method:

```
render() {
  this.state.readyToRedirect
    ? <Redirect to="/FinishedPaying" />
    : other stuffs...
```

*or in my opinion, a more readable way:*

```
render() {
  if (this.state.readyToRedirect) return <Redirect to="/FinishedPaying" />

  return (
    // rest of the code
  )
```

---

I also wouldn't define `onSuccess` function inside `render`, every state change will trigger render and re-define the function again and again.

If it doesn't require anything from `this`, you can even put it outside of the class

```
const onSuccess = payment => {
  ...
}

export default class Pay extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. These solutions work, in that they render correctly, but only if they are put above the Paypal logic (thus not running that logic.

Comment: The answer is to set the flag to `true` after the Paypal logic runs. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class Pay extends React.Component {

 state = {
  redirect: false
 };

renderRedirect = () => {
  if(this.state.redirect){
   return (
     <Redirect
       to="/FinishedPaying"
       userInput={this.props.userInput}
     />
    );
  }
};

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ redirect: true });
}

render() {
const onSuccess = payment => {
  axios
    .post(
      "http://amazonaws.com:3000/ethhash",
      {
        userInput: this.props.userInput,
      }
    )

    .then(response => console.log(response.data, payment))

    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

 return (
   <div>
    {this.renderRedirect()}
    <PaypalExpressBtn
      onSuccess={onSuccess}
    />
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works but it bypasses the Paypal logic, which is a necessary component of the page.