# What component lifecycle to use to do something before render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need to check whether some props (from redux store) is an empty object or not. If it is empty, I want the page to redirect to another page and not bother to call `render()`.

The current flow is something like:

```
constructor(props) {
   this.checkObject();
}

checkObject() {
  if (Object.keys(someObj).length === 0 && someObj.constructor === Object) {
    this.props.history.push("/some-other-route");
  }
}

render() {
   // some code
}
```

However, when I do a `console.log`, `render()` is being called after `checkObject()` which causes some errors because `render()` needs a non-empty object to display content properly. That's the reason I don't want react to even call `render()` if the object is empty (which I check through `checkObject()`) and just redirect to another page.

So is there a lifecycle method to use that will execute my redirection code before `render()` is called?

Comment: `render` will be called no matter what. However you can do `this.state.isValid: this.checkObject()` and in render, `this.state.isValid ? <JSX> : null`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Redirect component of react-router within render.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
render(){

 (checkIfObjectEmpty)?<Redirect to = '/some_route'/>:<JSX>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return inside render

```
constructor(props) {
    this.checkObject();
}

checkObject() {
    return Object.keys(someObj).length === 0 && someObj.constructor === Object
}

render() {
    if(this.checkObject()) return <Redirect to=/some-other-route" />

    //rest of code not run if object is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Add `super(props)` to your constructor. I think it should solve the problem. In this case, no need to `componentWillMount()`. Your code should work just fine.

**Unsafe and temporary solution:**
You can use [`componentWillMount()`](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/premounting_with_componentwillmount.html).

> The first true life cycle method called is componentWillMount(). This method is only called one time, which is before the initial render.

```
constructor(props) {

}

checkObject() {
  if (Object.keys(someObj).length === 0 && someObj.constructor === Object) {
    this.props.history.push("/some-other-route");
  }
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.checkObject();
}

render() {
   // some code
}
```

Comment: componentWillMount() method is unsafe as it is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you. It's unsafe but not deprecated yet. But this is good point, if there will be no method like this, how could we do such **before-render** things. I don't like to put this things in `render()` because with every render (for instance after `setState()`) the code runs, which is unnecessary.

Comment: React documentation prefers  `constructor()`  method for initializing states and for API calls you can use `componentDidMount()`

Comment: As in the question has been said, he/she don't want the render get called.

Answer (score 0):

`history.push()` is a side effect that won't prevent the component to be initially rendered, so it belongs to `componentDidMount`.

Since the result depends on props, the check could go to `getDerivedStateFromProps` to provide `redirect` flag in a component with local state. In a component that is connected to Redux it can be performed in `mapStateToProps`:

```
connect(({ someObj }) => ({ redirect: !Object.keys(someObj) }))(...)
```

The component shouldn't be rendered if it will redirect:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.redirect)
    this.props.history.push("/some-other-route");
}

render() {
   return !this.props.redirect && (
     ...
   );
}
```

As another answer correctly mentions, `<Redirect>` component is a declarative alternative to calling `history.push()` directly.